# Probability: Minimum Questions

Tags: probability

My professor gave us this question in class in the last lecture saying he did this one year in his introductory classes. I don't even think this can be solved (well, with what we learned in class at least) The question is:

I give my students 20 possible exam questions. Of those 20, 8 will be on the final exam. Of those 8, students must answer 6 questions of their choice. A lazy student does not want to review all his material. How many questions must he study to make sure that he can answer 6 questions?

Oh, and he said if you can give an explanation on the exam there might be bonus points... so I'm hoping to get that :P

Thanks.

Comment: Funny, I did almost the same problem this evening. I would suggest you have a look at the hypergeometric distribution. But you should clarify what 'make sure' really means in terms of the probability to know all the exam questions

Answer (score 3):

Hint: This has nothing to do with probability.  What happens if all the questions the student didn't study are on the exam?

Answer (score 0):

HINT: You must know answers to 6 questions out of chosen 8, so also remaining 12. (Why?)

Answer (score 0):

The question as posed is trivial - you are presented with 8 questions, you can ignore 2 so you better make sure you study the other 6. To be certain, you must study 20-2=18; worst case you get the 2 you didn't study plus 6 more. If you study any less than 18 there is a chance that 3 (or more) will be in the 8 selected.

More generally, the [Hypergeometric distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) is your friend here. For this problem:

$$N=20$$
$$K=\text{No of questions studied}$$
$$n=8$$
$$k=6,7 \text{ and  } 8$$

$$P(x>=6)={{K\choose6}{20-K\choose8-6}+{K\choose7}{20-K\choose8-7}+{K\choose8}{20-K\choose8-8}\over{20\choose8}}$$